# I believe I set up my rig correctly, but it still deforms after parenting with automatic weights?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigify

I cant figure out why my model is still deforming when I parent with automatic weights. All the transform are zeroed out. I applied the rest pose after I was done setting up the bones. Maybe the tail is causing an issue? I'm really not sure. is there another alternative is automatic weight aren't working out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: oh yes of course! [File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17uDqMzo5Gn2xArs0qcXjjqh7Xk2xmHbB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it works fine for me so I'm not sure why it doesn't for you, I hope someone will understand

Comment: Well I'm glad at least it works, but this is a new wrinkle haha. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: oh ok it needs a precision, actually I parented to the octahedral bones armature and it worked fine, as you're using a kind of auto-rig I, I suppose this armature should be controlled by the custom bones but it doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: @moonboots the "rig" armature is the generated animation rig of Rigify. The other one is just the metarig. It does not work for me if I use automatic weights for the rig. Re-generation doesn't help either (Blender 3.1.2). The upper arms and shoulders are pulled to the world origin (screenshot 1). The same happens with the shirt.

Comment: ok, I'm not familiar with Rigify or Auto-Rig so I don't know how to fix this  ;)

Comment: @Blunder I think the mesh is being pulled towards the rig's origin which happens to be at the world origin. If I move the origin of the rig to anywhere else, the mesh will pull towards there instead. [Origin Moved](https://imgur.com/a/WJ4JMSt) You think maybe its just a issue with 3.1.2?

Comment: I found an answer to my problem. Its related to the deform bones in the rig after you generate it. The OP's reply comment tell you the steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccFkm2NTQRg

Comment: Glad you found an answer. So it's the bendy bone settings of the generated rig? But why does this happen? When I use a new meta-rig, there is no problem. Except when I duplicate the tail from your meta-rig and connect it. If I create a new tail from scratch, it's fine again. By the way, you have to set the Rig Type to *spines.basic_tail* for the tail, otherwise no controls will be created.